# Error 'Cannot invoke an object which is possible undefined'

Tags: typescript

Here is the property and method

```
private errorMessages = new Map<string, () => string>();


public get errors(): Array<string> {
    if (!this.control) {
        return [];
    }

    const { errors } = this.control;
    return Object.keys(errors).map(key => this.errorMessages.has(key) ? 
  this.errorMessages.get(key)() : <string>errors[key] || key);
}
```

I get this error on this on this part of the code

```
this.errorMessages.get(key)()
```

Can someone explain why the problem as to why I'm getting this error and a possible solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because the return value of a [Map.prototype.get()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) is the element associated with the specified key or **undefined** if not found. You need to check whether `this.errorMessage.get(key)` actually returned a function before invoking it. The compiler does not know that Map.prototype.has() should work as a type guard, see this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13086) for more information.

You do check that the key exists with **this.errorMessages.has**, so you could use the bang operator (!) (`this.errorMessages.get(key)!()`) to tell the compiler you are certain it cannot be **undefined**. But then you don't have to check by calling **has** at all before the **get** as simply invoking **get** with a non existing key will return **undefined**:

```
return Object.keys(errors).map(key => this.errorMessages.get(key)?.() ?? <string>errors[key] ?? key);
```

Comment: I get an error on the code you have above.                                                                  Type '(string | (() => string))[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
  Type 'string | (() => string)' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type '() => string' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: Did you figure it out? I edited my answer. Forgot to call whatever was returned by `this.errorMessages.get(key)`.